# Having trouble writing to a text file

Tags: java, android

What I'm doing exactly is this: 
I have a class "Welcome" that calls another class "textWriter" which contains a method "write". Welcome passes two strings to "write", "name" is the name of the text file to write to and "something" is the thing to print.

i keep getting null pointer error on `prt = new PrintStream(output);`

here is the logcat

```
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileOutput(ContextWrapper.java:158)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at com.rhobot.budget.textWriter.write(textWriter.java:24)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at com.rhobot.budget.Welcome.setSubChoices(Welcome.java:37)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at com.rhobot.budget.Welcome$1.onClick(Welcome.java:76)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-22 16:40:22.561: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2245):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is the Welcome class:

```
public class Welcome extends Activity
{
P p = new P(); //shared prefs helper
loadArray la = new loadArray(); //array loader
textWriter tw = new textWriter();
private EditText txtBalance;
private Button btnEnter;
int subItemCount, addItemCount;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.welcomescreen);
    capture();
}
public static String sub_choice_key = "sub_choice_key.txt";
public static String sub_compare = "sub_compare.txt";
public static String add_choice_key = "add_choice_key.txt";
public static String add_compare = "add_compare.txt";

public void setSubChoices() throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO create a master list of choices
    tw.write(sub_choice_key,"-1");
    tw.write(sub_choice_key,"-2");
    tw.write(sub_choice_key,"-3");
    tw.write(sub_compare,"-1");
    tw.write(sub_compare,"-2");
    tw.write(sub_compare,"-3");
    p.pisI("subItemCount", 3, this);
}...
```

Here is the textWriter class

```
public class textWriter extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
public void write(String name, String something) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream output;
        output = openFileOutput(name,MODE_APPEND);
        PrintStream prt;
        prt = new PrintStream(output);
        prt.println(something);
        prt.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

id like to emphasize that these are two different files as well, and i am importing all the right stuff i believe.. also i have the line 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` 
in my android manifest.

what am i doing wrong? is it context? or lack there of? if so how should i implement it?

i am doing it this way because i want to use this textWrite in other programs as an easy (less messy) way of writing data.  in my main it could save me about 50 lines of code if i do it this way.
Thanks in advance-
Tricknology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As probablykevin said, the issue is a lack of a valid Context.

One simple fix you could do if you want your class structure to stay the same is to remove the `extends Activity` from `textWriter` and instead pass in a Context in the constructor, i.e.:

```
public class textWriter{
    private Context m_context;

    public textWriter(Context ctx) {
        m_context = ctx;
    }    
    public void write(String name, String something) {

        try {
            FileOutputStream output;
            output = m_context.openFileOutput(name,MODE_APPEND);
            PrintStream prt;
            prt = new PrintStream(output);
            prt.println(something);
            prt.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You'd then need to construct it like so: `textWriter tw = new textWriter(this);`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new Activity, place the write method in your original activity that you are calling it from.

The problem arises when textWriter calls openOutputStream() but has not been created yet. So yes, I would say it is a problem of Context because the context calling `openOutputStream()` has not been created yet.